# creating a simple layout on android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, emulation

I'm very new with android development. I'm trying to develop an application, I decided to try out the code below but I keep getting errors when I try to open it on the emulator. please can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
package hajara.android.MyRecipes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyRecipesActivity extends Activity {
  Button btn;
  TextView t1, t2;
  EditText e;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
     t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
      e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
     btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

   btn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
 }

}
```

My main.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter a string:"
/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:editable="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
/>
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="OK"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should also put the log cat also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onClick listener is done incorrectly. I find it easier to simply create a method such as:

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    // Do something
}
```

and within your XML layout file (ie. main.xml) invoke the onClick attribute:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't Declared button Properly.

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Your Code Goes here
        }
    });
```

And Hope you have Declared your Activity in Manifest File.